# Introductory material on psychotherapy

Tags: reference-request

As a complete outsider to the subject, I would like to start learning about psychotherapy. To this end would you be able to suggest a starting point, say, an introductory book which I can go through, to then start exploring more and more specific directions?

Related: [What books should I study to have a decent understanding of psychology?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8051/what-books-should-i-study-to-have-a-decent-understanding-of-psychology)

Answer (score 2):

As provided in the top answer to [What books should I study to have a decent understanding of psychology?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/8051/what-books-should-i-study-to-have-a-decent-understanding-of-psychology), I’ve compiled a reading list based on the books I acquired during my training as a therapist.  The first section is a **general introduction** and they would answer your question on introductory material. I highly recommend reading these before going into the other 2 sections.

I have added the 2nd and 3rd sections for further reading. For a good understanding, I recommend you don't touch any of the books in the 3rd section unless you have a good grasp on the books in section 2.

I have often quoted from these books in my answers here.

### General Introduction (Best read in order)

Sanders, P. (2011). *First steps in counselling: A students' companion for introductory courses.* Pccs Books.

Frankland, A., & Sanders, P. (1995). *Next steps in counselling: a students' companion for certificate and counselling skills courses.* PCCS books.

Reeves, A. (2022). *An introduction to counselling and psychotherapy: From theory to practice. An Introduction to Counselling and Psychotherapy* Sage. [Contents and Chapter 1 Preview (PDF)](http://216.104.201.186:5050/xmlui/bitstream/handle/123456789/61/Intro_to_C&P_Chapter_1.pdf?sequence=1)

De Board, R. (2008). *Counselling for toads: a psychological adventure.* Routledge.

### To be read after the general introductory for best understanding

Clarkson, P., & Cavicchia, S. (2013). *Gestalt counselling in action.* Sage.

Dryden, W., Jones, J., & Trower, P. (2015). *Cognitive behavioural counselling in action. Cognitive Behavioural Counselling in Action.* Sage

Jacobs, M. (2017). *Psychodynamic counselling in action.* Sage.

Mearns, D., Thorne, B., & McLeod, J. (2013). *Person-centred counselling in action*. Sage.

Rogers, C. (2012). *Client Centred Therapy (New Ed).* Hachette UK.

### Further reading when you have a good grasp of the other 2 sections

Berne, E. (1968). *Games people play: The psychology of human relationships.* Penguin

Erickson, J. M., & Erickson, J. M. (1997). The life cycle completed: Extended version with new chapters on the ninth stage of development.

Harris, T. A. (2012). *I'm OK, you're OK.* Random House.

Jacobs, M. (2012). *The Presenting Past: The Core Of Psychodynamic Counselling And Therapy: The core of psychodynamic counselling and therapy.* McGraw-Hill Education (UK).

Sigelman, C. K., & Rider, E. A. (2021). *Life-span human development.* 10th ed. Cengage Learning.